# Making content appear below the :before pseudo selector?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-content

I have an element

```
<div class="Test_then">The result is ...</div>
```

The `Test_then` class looks like this:

```
.Test_then::before {
  content: 'Then';
}
```

My goal is to have the (`The result is ...`) appear below the `Then` content added by the `Test_then` class.  So in other words in would render like this:

```
Then
The result is ...
```

Comment: ok. Where is your code??

Comment: It's right there. Well the HTML wasn't there, but the CSS certainly was, and it's fairly hard to miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your generated content simply consists of the word "Then" inline, you can just add a newline with `\a`, and use `white-space: pre-wrap` (or `pre`) to cause the newline to render as an actual line break:

```
.Test_then::before {
  content: 'Then\a';
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

An example of this is also provided in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/generate.html#content).

If your generated content needs to be displayed as a block for any reason, then it becomes even simpler — `display: block` alone will have the same effect:

```
.Test_then::before {
  content: 'Then';
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: OK - I know I'm supposed to avoid thanks - but you're awesome - THANKS!!